# N[Product] and NProduct give different results

Tags: special-functions, summation, numerical-value, products

I have some trouble. I've been using finite product to study a certain function (see below). However, when I wanted to compute it precisely, I decided to use `NProduct` with infinite limits. But for some reason it gives incorrect values.

Here is the finite product with $N=100$:

```
$MaxExtraPrecision=2000;
MatrixForm[Table[{j,N[Product[(1-Exp[- j (1/2+n)^2]),{n,-100,100}],20]},{j,1,20}]]
1   0.039007054895361795721
2   0.15139635144655065425
3   0.27774549346550162147
4   0.39947778367746877970
5   0.50906216159898177044
6   0.60352509325118028099
7   0.68264929923843500277
8   0.74764504964227035168
9   0.80031054484515174785
10  0.84256794946618008401
11  0.87623104899379818870
12  0.90290461543754440198
13  0.92395502352916748007
14  0.94051711512087823934
15  0.95351759265812542029
16  0.96370418485043370418
17  0.97167500055101208612
18  0.97790541672760206152
19  0.98277146142364643170
20  0.98656950593159155060
```

Here is the finite product with $N=10000$ (no difference):

```
$MaxExtraPrecision=2000;
MatrixForm[Table[{j,N[Product[(1-Exp[- j (1/2+n)^2]),{n,-10000,10000}],20]},{j,1,20}]]
1   0.039007054895361795721
2   0.15139635144655065425
3   0.27774549346550162147
4   0.39947778367746877970
5   0.50906216159898177044
6   0.60352509325118028099
7   0.68264929923843500277
8   0.74764504964227035168
9   0.80031054484515174785
10  0.84256794946618008401
11  0.87623104899379818870
12  0.90290461543754440198
13  0.92395502352916748007
14  0.94051711512087823934
15  0.95351759265812542029
16  0.96370418485043370418
17  0.97167500055101208612
18  0.97790541672760206152
19  0.98277146142364643170
20  0.98656950593159155060
```

And here is the values computed using `NProduct`:

```
$MaxExtraPrecision=2000;
MatrixForm[Table[{j,NProduct[(1-Exp[- j (1/2+n)^2]),{n,-Infinity,Infinity},WorkingPrecision->20]},{j,1,20}]]
1   0.395004075398529506
2   0.778193681409841966
3   1.054031296433842369
4   1.264085097890911425
5   1.426971844990617564
6   1.553737549589608497
7   1.652451874323043640
8   1.729329407189122372
9   1.789201548004194801
10  1.835830002441598713
11  1.872144277553199892
12  1.900425863260700209
13  1.922451584336175141
14  1.939605233155322500
15  1.952964508287977486
16  1.963368722222531184
17  1.971471532182001441
18  1.977782006923515382
19  1.982696609593758731
20  1.986524106001829066
```

The values are incorrect (they should be approaching $1$, not $2$) and I don't see any substantial change in my code except for using `NProduct`.

> What is wrong here? Why are the values in the last case wrong?

I use Mathematica 10.3, student edition.

---

The finite product gives the correct values, since I've checked for an alternative expression:

```
$MaxExtraPrecision = 2000;
MatrixForm[Table[{j, Exp[-Sqrt[Pi/j] NSum[1/k^(3/2) EllipticTheta[3,Pi/2,E^(-(\[Pi]^2/(k j)))],{k,1,Infinity}, WorkingPrecision->10]]},{j, 1, 20}]]
1   0.0390070620
2   0.1513963515
3   0.2777454935
4   0.3994777837
5   0.5090621616
6   0.6035250933
7   0.6826492992
8   0.7476450496
9   0.8003105448
10  0.8425679495
11  0.8762310490
12  0.9029046154
13  0.92395502354
14  0.94051711513
15  0.95351759266
16  0.96370418485
17  0.97167500055
18  0.97790541673
19  0.98277146142
20  0.98656950594
```

Comment: Note `NProduct` works for either one sided infinite interval, you can do `NProduct[ .. {0,Infinity}]` or `NProduct[ .. {-Infinity,0}]`

Comment: hmm... `NProduct[(1 - Exp[-10 (1/2 + n)^2]), {n, 0, Infinity}] + 
 NProduct[(1 - Exp[-10 (1/2 + n)^2]), {n, -Infinity, -1}]` yields the exact  same as `NProduct[(1 - Exp[-10 (1/2 + n)^2]), {n, -Infinity, Infinity}]`  Obviously the half intervals ought to be multiplied, not added..  bug..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A bit of re-writing can get around this:

```
$MaxExtraPrecision = 2000;
expr = 1 - Exp[-j (1/2 + n)^2];
approx = Table[
          {j, NProduct[expr^2, {n, 0, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]}, {j, 1, 20}];

Grid[approx]
1   0.0390070548953617957
2   0.1513963514465506542
3   0.277745493465501621
4   0.399477783677468780
5   0.509062161598981770
6   0.603525093251180281
7   0.682649299238435003
8   0.747645049642270352
9   0.800310544845151748
10  0.842567949466180084
11  0.876231048993798189
12  0.902904615437544402
13  0.923955023529167480
14  0.940517115120878239
15  0.953517592658125420
16  0.963704184850433704
17  0.971675000551012086
18  0.977905416727602062
19  0.982771461423646432
20  0.986569505931591551
```